What is the correct frequentist interpretation of hypothesis testing?
I understand the frequentist interpretation of a confidence interval with a confidence level of X% (I think): Imagine taking many random samples and following the procedure to calculate a CI for all of them. X% of their intervals will contain the true parameter.
However, I am getting confused when I try to interpret hypothesis testing in a similar way. I feel like there should be a similar interpretation since checking if a value $\mu_0$ is in a 95% confidence interval is mathematically the same as checking whether or not you would reject the hypothesis of $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$.
My thought process is to define the procedure of a hypothesis test, imagine repeating it many times, and see how often we are correct. However, how often we are correct depends on what the true $\mu$ is, which is leading to my confusion.
What is the standard frequentist interpretation?
